# How do I write out Hangul (Korean) to a file?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am trying to write out English, Japanese and Korean in the same file.

This is what I do:

```
new File("genned/test123.txt").write("안녕하세요　hello こんにち", "utf8")
```

The resulting file ends up containing `�壱��們┷��hello縲�％繧薙↓縺｡`

What do I need to do to get the Korean and Japanese to show up properly?

UPDATE:
I tried this:

```
File file = new File("genned/test123.txt");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
out.println("日本");
out.close();
```

And the output was: `譌･譛ｬ`

And viewed in a hex editor the bytes were: `E8 AD 8C EF BD A5 E8 AD 9B EF BD AC 0A`

UPDATE:

When I try printing the string `"\u65E5\u672C"`, the file correctly ends up with the string `日本`

Comment: Are you sure the file does not contain the correct characters? How do you check?

Comment: How do you inspect the file? Text editor? Did you compare the utf8 codepoints if it is the right character being written? I suspect that the font the editor is using might not be able to properly display the characters.

Comment: File class is your custom class? java.io.File does not contain write method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: @Femaref Textedit couldn't open the file for some reason, so I was inspecting in Intellij, and Chrome, and both showed the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check that the encoding in the **editor** and of the **java compiler** are the same "UTF-8".

```
File file = new File("genned/test123.txt");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
out.println("안하세요　hello こんにち");
out.close();
```

---

***After your update:***

Check that the source is in UTF-8. Use for instance [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org) a free programmer's editor with many encodings. And compile with `javac -encoding UTF-8 ...`.

My guess is that the editor is okay (as it represents both Japanese and Korean, so that probably the compiler still uses the default platform operating system encoding.

If using eclipse look at Windows / Preferences / General / Workspace / Text file encoding.
And project settings.